# reset/clear selected values in select-option on button click in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, select-options

I'm working on react and I have several drop-down and text fields where I want to clear/reset selected values from the select options and from the text field when I click the clear button. I've tried some logic, but it doesn't work. can someone help me? I created a function called **"handleReset"** but it does nothing and doesn't show an error.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Container,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { CarAction } from "../../Store/Actions/CarAction";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const CarRequests = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const getCarMake = useSelector((state) => state.CarReducer.car);
  const getCarMileage = useSelector((state) => state.CarReducer.mileage);
  const getCarTrim = useSelector((state) => state.CarReducer.trim);

  let [value, setValue] = useState()

  let handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleReset = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value = "");
  }

 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(CarAction.CarMake());
    dispatch(CarAction.CarMileage());
    dispatch(CarAction.CarTrim());
  }, [dispatch]);

 
  return (
    <div className="flex-row align-items-center section">
      <h3>
        Filters
        <i className="fa fa-cog icon float-right"></i>
      </h3>
      <Container className="box-shadow p-4">
        <div className="form-row">
          <div className="form-group col-lg-3">
            <label>Make:</label>
            <select className="custom-select" onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value=''>Please select...</option>
              {getCarMake.map((data, key) => <option value={data.value} key={key}>{data.name}</option>)}
            </select>

          </div>

          <div className="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Model:</label>
            <select className="custom-select">
            <option value=''>Please select...</option>
              <option value="1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="3">Option 3</option>

            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Year:</label>
            <select className="custom-select">
            <option value=''>Please select...</option>
              <option value="1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Mileage:</label>
            <select className="custom-select" onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value=''>Please select...</option>
              {getCarMileage.map((data, key) => <option value={data.value} key={key}>{data.name}</option>)}

            </select>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div className="form-row">

          <div className="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Car Trim:</label>
            <select className="custom-select" onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value=''>Please select...</option>
              {getCarTrim.map((data, key) => <option value={data.value} key={key}>{data.name}</option>)}

            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" className="custom-select" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Phone no:</label>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Phone no" className="custom-select" />
          </div>

        </div>
        <div className="container-buttons">
          <Button className="mr-4" variant="light">
            Search
          </Button>

          <Button variant="dark" onClick={handleReset}>Clear</Button>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarRequests;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are doing wrong is in handleReset function you are taking the event and you are setting the target value to empty which is ideally wrong.
In order to correct it we need to understand how the flow is working, you are using handleChange function in order to set the values to your state.
So in order to reset it you need to reset the value of the state only.

So the code becomes like this:

```
const handleReset = () => {
    setValue("");   
}
```

Now this will reset the value of your state variable and also use your state variable in your select method which will resolve the problem.

```
<select value={value}>
<option></option>
.
.
</select>
```

To make dynamic field working:

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({});
  const arr = ["hello", "cra"];
  const arr2 = [
    {
      name: "hello",
      id: "1",
    },
    {
      name: "test2",
      id: "2",
    },
  ];

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value: val, name } }) => {
    setValue({ ...value, [name]: val });
  };

  const resetValue = () => {
    setValue({});
  };

  console.log(value);

  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      <select
        name="select1"
        value={value.select1 || ""}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <option value=""></option>
        {arr.map((val) => {
          return <option value={val}>{val}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
      <select
        name="select2"
        value={value.select2 || ""}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <option value=""></option>
        {arr2.map(({ name, id }) => {
          return <option value={id}>{name}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
      <button onClick={resetValue}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or else you can initialise the value in your state as well like this

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({select1: "" , select2: ""});
```

which could further be used dynamically in your select tag for name attributes.

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({ select1: "", select2: "" });
  const arr = ["hello", "cra"];
  const arr2 = [
    {
      name: "hello",
      id: "1",
    },
    {
      name: "test2",
      id: "2",
    },
  ];

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value: val, name } }) => {
    setValue({ ...value, [name]: val });
  };

  const resetValue = () => {
    setValue({
      select1: "",
      select2: "",
    });
  };

  console.log(value);

  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      <select name="select1" value={value.select1} onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value=""></option>
        {arr.map((val) => {
          return <option value={val}>{val}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
      <select name="select2" value={value.select2} onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value=""></option>
        {arr2.map(({ name, id }) => {
          return <option value={id}>{name}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
      <button onClick={resetValue}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine, but now there is a new problem. As I said, I have multiple dropdowns, if I select the value from the first dropdown menu and then select the option from the second dropdown menu, the value of the first dropdown automatically reset without clicking on clear button

Comment: I have added the code snippet. Have a look if it helps. Thanks!
You just need to make the things dynamic, if you are using just one state variable.
Hope it helps!

Comment: It still has the same issue when I select the value of another dropdown the, the value of first dropdown automatically deselect

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lgdemr?file=src/App.js
Pls have a look here. It works perfect in here. I am not sure how you have mapped your data.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to store multiple values in the `value` . don't use the word value there. I have tried to change it to `[formValue, setFormValue]`

Change 1:

```
let [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
textfield1: '',
dropdownfield2: ''});
```

Change 2 - for dropdown changed values:

```
const handlDropDownChange = (event, value) => {
    setFormValue({
        ...formValue,
        ['dropdownfield2']: value,
    });
}
```

Change 3 - for mapping dropdown values from state, also use this to map to dropdown value:

```
formValue.dropdownfield2
```

Change 4 - for text field changes:

```
onChange={e => {
    updateFieldMyForm(e);
}}

const updateFieldMyForm= e => {
    setFormValue({
        ...formValue,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
};
```

Note this will work for all text fields - just make sure that the name of this textfield matches the name used in the `useState` statement like - `textfield1`

Change 5 - to reset the whole thing at the end/submission

EDIT - 1

const handleReset = () => { setFormValue({ textfield1: "", dropdownfield2: "" }); };

Spread operator is the key in steps 2 & 4 [triple dots - ...] - let me know if you still have challenges.

Comment: I have followed your steps and now no data is displaying in my dropdown which I'm getting from API and managing through redux

Comment: 1. Please share the modified code for dropdown - are you binding it correctly with the new state variable - like this :
     value={formValue.dropdownfieldname}  

2. Also confirm if the value of textboxes is working.

Comment: I have modified the code now my data is displaying perfectly again but clear button doesn't clear fields.

check my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/waqasumer/mytq02du/2/

Comment: Fiddle didn't work for me somehow. 

Meanwhile just make this change :

  const handleReset = () => {
    setFormValue({
    textfield1: "",
    dropdownfield2: ""
  });
  };